# Add inner shadow to a circle image inline css

Tags: html, image, css

I'm trying to add inner shadow to a circle image. Since it's written for an html email, it's inline css.

I have this:

```
<td style="border:3px solid #ffffff;border-radius: 50px 50px;box-shadow: 0 0 20px 0px #000000 inset">
 <span><img style="border-radius: 50px 50px;" src="http://media.futuresmag.com/futuresmag/article/2012/05/15/dec29facebook-logo-crop-96x96.jpg"></span>
</td>
```

I get the circle part and the white border, I'm also getting a tiny black border that should be the shadow.

Who knows how to solve that?

(I picked a facebook icon for illustration)

Tnx!

Comment: If this is a HTML email, box-shadow [doesn't actually work in any email client](http://www.campaignmonitor.com/css/), so even if you can get it to work, it won't ever show up..

Answer (score 3):

Ok, maybe you could try doing something like this:

```
<div style="border-radius: 50px 50px;
            background:url(http://media.futuresmag.com/futuresmag/article/2012/05/15/dec29facebook-logo-crop-96x96.jpg);
            width:96px;height:96px;
            box-shadow: inset 0 0 5px 5px #f00;">
</div>
```

Instead of using an IMG I used a div with a background image, this way the box shadow I'm using gets applied on top of the image.